# How react Infinite Queries support with offset and limit

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-query

I tried to implement an infinite scroll with my react.js project using **Infinite Queries in react-query** and **react-virtual**. But Infinite query is supporting with the cursor and the page. and my API is not supported for pages, and it has a limit, offset, and totalCount in the metaData as below

`meta: { limit: 100, offset: 0, total: 1000}`

Are Infinite Queries support for limit and offset?

There are links that I followed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-virtual/tree/master/examples/infinite-scroll

https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/guides/infinite-queries

Answer (score 4):

`infiniteQueries` don't really care *how* your backend delivers a "cursor" to the next page, it just matters that the backend delivers *something*.

Basically, whatever is returned from `getNextPageParam` will be injected into the queryFn as `pageParam`. Here is an example that might fit your use-case:

```
const { data } = useInfiniteQuery(
    'key',
    ({ pageParam }) => axios.get(myUrl + '?offset=' + pageParam?.offset ?? 0),
    {
        getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage?.meta
    }
)
```

The concept of a "page" is merely what ever your backend returns for a single fetch. So here, on the first fetch (for page 0), we have no pageParam, so we initalize with `offset: 0`. Then, we fetch with that, and the backend returns the first set of data (a page), and we extract the meta info for it (offset = 20 or whatever).

If you call `fetchNextPage()`, the queryFn will be called with that meta information, so the next fetch does `?offset=20`. The backend delivers offset: 40 as meta and the infinity continues.

Hope that explains it :)

Comment: Your code fragment is syntactically wrong.

Comment: I updated the syntax

Comment: Where is the .meta coming from?

Comment: From the backend response.